# R plots on OpenBSD show graphics but text is replaced with placeholder images

Tags: r, openbsd

I've recently migrated from Arch to OpenBSD.  My R code is generally running as expected, but I'm having strange plotting behavior: the non-textual elements of the graph are fine, but all axes labels, titles, and legend text is replaced with a square gif.  The example below is a basic plot, but the same issues shows up regardless of the plot packaged used (e.g. ggplot)

```
plot(1:10)
```

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9cYc.png)

For this basic plot, if I first issue the command

```
par(family="Arial")
```

then the text/labels are displayed correctly, but this doesn't necessarily carry over to ggplot2.  I'm guessing it has something to do woth my font-conf, any help appreciated.

Here is my sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-openbsd6.7 (64-bit)
Running under: OpenBSD puffyx1.my.domain 6.7 GENERIC.MP#234 amd64

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so.37.0
LAPACK: /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so.37.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://rpubs.com/gbonafe/ggplot2-font) helped me solve same issue.
I installed this font:

`sudo pkg_add liberation-fonts`

Below test code:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col = Species)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme(text = element_text(family = "Liberation"))
```

Answer (score 0):

same issue on 6.7, R compiled from ports

write your own `~/.Rprofile`

`cat ~/.Rprofile`

```
# default X11() setting
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),
    function(...) grDevices::X11.options(width = 8, height = 8, xpos = 0, pointsize = 10, type = "x11"))
###
```

now `plot(1:10)` works